# What is a neat way to load and store a list of images by name in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

I want to load a list (or any data structure) of images using a bunch of hardcoded names and an existing function `loadImage :: String -> IO Image`.

In Lua, I would do the following:

```
imageNames = {"background", "gun", "man"}

images = {}
for i,v in ipairs(imageNames) do
    images[v] = loadImage(v..".png")
end
```

And access them with `images.background`, `images.man` etc. How could I go about this in Haskell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import Data.Map

imageNames :: [String]
imageNames = ["background", "gun", "man"]

images :: [IO (String, Image)]
images = [loadImage(name ++ ".png") >>= return . (,) name | name <- imageNames]

main = do
  imgs <- sequence images
  let imageMap = fromList imgs
  return ()
```

imageMap is a `Map` from which you can access a image by its name : `imageMap ! "gun"`

Comment: `m >>= return . f` = `f <$> m`

Answer (score 2):

Basically what Ankur said, I probably wouldn't have an explicit 'images' list and would probably use JuicyPixels to do the loading:

```
import Data.Map
import Codec.Picture

images :: [String]
images = ["background", "gun", "man"]

main = do
  imgs <- mapM loadImage images
  let imageMap = fromList (zip images imgs)
  return ()

loadImage :: IO DynamicImage
loadImage = either id (error "Bad Image") `fmap` readImage
```

Comment: That's nice but I just wanted to stick to using SDL's images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but here's another way to do it. It works on a slightly different principle than the other solutions, but the end result is the same.

```
import Data.Map (insert, empty)
import Data.List (foldl')
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Control.Monad (forM)

imageNames = ["background", "gun", "man"]

images = foldl' (flip id) empty <$> forM imageNames (\name ->
    insert name <$> loadImage (name ++ ".png")
  )
```

What `images` does is that it builds a list of `insert` operations that are waiting to be performed on a `Map`. It then uses `foldl'` to thread a `Map` through the list of `insert` operations. As the fold goes along it uses the `insert` operations to build a larger and larger `Map` with the desired values. In other words, this does not build an intermediary `[(String, Image)]` which it then converts to a `Map String Int`.

The `IO` is carried all the way from `loadImage` to the outer function with `<$>` and `sequence`, giving the resulting type `IO (Map String Image)`.

I think the other solutions are much easier to read (and probably a lot more efficient as well), so I recommend one of them. I just wanted to throw this out there.